# Unable connect oracle 10g XE to django

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to connect to oracle 10g XE database from windows but getting following error

[image] 
Here is my settings for database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'xe',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '1527',
    }
}
```

installed libraries

```
cx-Oracle==6.1
Django==1.11.10
pytz==2018.3
```

Tried to identify solutions but found nothing related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was cx-Oracle version. unfortunately cx-Oracle 6.1 does not support oracle 10g so downgraded to cx-Oracle 5.3 and connection was established successfully

```
cx-Oracle==5.3
```